# Is there a way to make IE8 honour opacity on an `:before` pseudo element?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, opacity, pseudo-element

I have this simple CSS...

```
div:before {
    content: "G'day";   
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    -moz-opacity: .4;
    opacity: .4;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/2fhVc/).

The `:before` pseudo element has the correct opacity in Firefox 6. In IE8, the opacity is not applied.

[Typically](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/PzTcG/), setting the opacity on the `div` works, but that isn't what I want.

I tried adding `display: block` but it didn't help.

Whilst I *could* workaround this, is there any trick to get IE8 to honour the `opacity` property on a `:before` (and `:after` for that matter) pseudo element?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I had the same problem a while back, and I ended up just working around it.

Comment: @thirtydot: Thanks for checking it out for me. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

I had the same problem a while back, and I ended up just working around it (by not using `:before`).

[image]

Here's some sound reasoning as to *why* it's not possible: [Why does a filter gradient on a pseudo element not work in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403916/why-does-a-filter-gradient-on-a-pseudo-element-not-work-in-ie8/10669986#10669986)