# Fixed positioned pseudo-element in IE8 bug

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css-position, pseudo-element

## Background

I have a standard three column layout where the first column is floated left, and the third column is floated right. The first column needs a full-height background.

- This layout is for a template, so any of the three columns could have the longest content.
- I can't change markup source order, so `display:table` solutions are not possible.
- I can't add any DOM nodes.
- The layout is centered with a minimum and maximum width, so I can't attach a vertically-repeating background image to the page with the built-in background color.
- It needs to look OK in IE7, but IE8+ needs support.

## Solution

To achieve the full-height left column, I created a pseudo-element on `colLeft`. That pseudo-element has fixed-positioning set to the viewport bottom, 100% height, and placed behind the left column. This solution is awesome because:

- IE8+ supports pseudo-elements.
- The pseudo-element is attached to the left column, so if the template doesn't have a left column, the background naturally isn't there.
- By not setting a `left` or `right` attribute, the fixed-positioned pseudo-element stays with the left column (good for the centered layout).

Here's an [example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/mattrosno/full/bmFpy).

(Make sure that the Document Mode is following the Browser Mode when viewing CodePens in IE).

## Problem

In IE8 the full-height left column background only extends down to the initial viewport bottom (the fold).

I [created another test](http://codepen.io/mattrosno/full/zclbG) with a new `leftColBg` node instead of the pseudo-element. This works as expected in IE8, meaning that the fixed positioning should work.

Here is the best explanation that I can find on IE8 and generated content: [Why does a filter gradient on a pseudo element not work in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403916/why-does-a-filter-gradient-on-a-pseudo-element-not-work-in-ie8/10669986#10669986)

I think IE8 is incorrectly positioning the generated content, because it's not an "object" that contains content. Can anybody better explain this IE8 bug? Is there a fix?

Comment: Sorry - no answer to this but I think I came across the same issue. Using body:content then adding position fixed didn't fix the element. But adding a div in the markup and then using the same CSS as the psuedo element worked as expected.