# Cannot rotate :after pseudo-element using CSS in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have an absolutely-positioned box:

```
#box {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

which has an "arrow" coming off it, really an absolutely-positioned square in an :after pseudo-element. To make it look like an arrow, I want to rotate the square 45 degrees counter-clockwise:

```
#box:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    left: -6px;
    right: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    border-left: 1px solid #666;
    background-color: #fff;
    content: "";
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

This works fine, except for IE8. To make it rotate in IE8, I added the rule:

```
#box:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067811865482, M12=0.7071067811865466, M21=-0.7071067811865466, M22=0.7071067811865482), SizingMethod='auto expand'";
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I've verified that the -ms-filter works: for example, if I apply that rule to the #box element, the #box rotates in IE8. But the :after pseudo-element doesn't recognize the -ms-filter rule. Does anybody know if it's possible to rotate an :after pseudo-element in IE8, and if so, how?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403916/why-does-a-filter-gradient-on-a-pseudo-element-not-work-in-ie8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters do not work on Pseudo elements in IE8. No-can-do.

IF IE8 support is a must, your best bet is to make #box:after it's own div. Not the cleanest solution, but is any hack for IE8?

Comment: Thanks; it's helpful just to be told it's not possible. I don't think I can create a new div just for IE8, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has partial support for Pseudo elements... Check this [**Link**](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/)

`:after` to work in `IE8`, a `<!DOCTYPE>` must be declared.
Also,

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
```

You'll note from the above that IE8 has different syntax to IE6/7. You need to supply both lines of code if you want to support all versions of IE.

I have taken some of the portion From this excellent answer.

**[CSS rotate property in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie)**

good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of these things. I do have a <!DOCTYPE HTML> declared. I don't need to support IE6/7.