# IE8 fails to parse :after element CSS properties

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

IE8 fails to apply some property for no apparent reason.

Giving this HTML :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            h1:after {
                position: absolute;
                content: "test";
                top: 20%;
                left: 20%;
                background: red;
                filter: alpha(opacity=65);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>-</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

IE8 doesn't render the opacity property. It only works if I try to apply on h1 (and not :after)...

IE8 css tab clearly show a css bug (property value concatenated), renders some bugged property but doesn't render some others (like opacity) :
[image]

Can someone reproduce this bug and help me resolve it ?

Thanks

Comment: see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510268/is-there-a-way-to-make-ie8-honour-opacity-on-an-before-pseudo-element

Comment: It's been comented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8 - That IE8 needs a layout to the element to apply opacity. So try adding a `display: inline-block` to it.

Comment: @LcSalazar: tried without success